# Tomcat SSO windows authentication

Tags: linux, tomcat, active-directory, single-sign-on

Is there any frameworks for windows authentication like Waffle?
It's really easy to config, no Kerberos keytab configuration or adding user to AD required,but not working on linux.
As I read about another products like Jespa, SPNEGO/Kerberos Authenticator or Spring Security they need to add account in AD, create keytab, setSPN...
Waffle no need to do all this things on domain controller.
Now I'm using Tomcat 7 on WinServer2012, GWT 2.5.0. We are trying to move tomcat on RedOS server.